# Domain of an iterated homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, group-homomorphism

Suppose I have a homomorphism $\phi: {\rm dom(\phi)}\to G$, where I know ${\rm dom}(\phi)$ is a finite index subgroup of $G$. I am interested in what happens when you look at a high iterate of this homomorphism. This gets complicated though, since ${\rm dom}(\phi)$ is potententially not invariant. In other words, $\phi({\rm dom}(\phi))\not\subseteq {\rm dom}(\phi),$ so $\phi$ is not in general self-composable.

For the rest of the post, I will write $\phi^2=\phi\circ\phi$ to denote the homomorphism defined on the restricted domain ${\rm dom}(\phi)\cap \phi({\rm dom}(\phi))$, which is exactly where this homomorphism is possible to define. I will denote this restricted domain as ${\rm dom}(\phi^2)$. In general, if $K_1={\rm dom}(\phi)$, then $\phi^n$ will be used to denote the iterated homomorphism defined on $K_n = K_{n-1}\cap \phi(K_{n-1})$, and I will write $K_n=:{\rm dom}(\phi^n)$.

Now, it's not too hard to show that ${\rm dom}(\phi^N)$ will have finite index in $G$. You just show that if $[G:{\rm dom}(\phi)] =:d$, then $[{\rm dom}(\phi):{\rm dom}(\phi^2)]\leq d$ as well. Then you can use that
$$G\geq {\rm dom}(\phi)\geq {\rm dom}(\phi^2)\geq \dotsm\geq{\rm dom}(\phi^N)$$
to conclude that $[G:{\rm dom}(\phi)]\leq d^N$.

My problem requires infinite iteration though. So my question is when will
$$K:=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty {\rm dom}(\phi^n)$$
be nontrivial and finite index in $G$? Although I have no explicit example, I am almost certain that the nontrivial-ness and finite-index will not be true in general. But are there nice (optimistically: easily checkable) properties that might guarantee this? It could even be looser: rather than $K$ itself being finite index, I would be happy to find nonempty $H\leq K$ with $[G:H]<\infty$.

Even if there aren't nice answers to my soft questions, does anyone know of a reference discussing "iterated homomorphisms"?

Edit: changed "nonempty" to "nontrivial"

Comment: Huh? The domain of $\phi^n$ is the same as the domain of $\phi$ for all $n\geq 1$. In general, the domain of $f\circ g$ is the same as the domain of $g$. Are you actually thinking about *images*? It is certainly true that in general $\mathrm{im}(\phi^{n+2})\leq\mathrm{im}(\phi^n)$, and you need not have equality...

Comment: Sorry, I maybe explained the issue poorly in the post. The problem is, for $h\in{\rm dom}(\phi)$, $\phi(h)$ might fall *outside* of the domain. So $\phi(\phi(h))$ is not defined. Thus you can have $h\in{\rm dom}(\phi)$ for which $h\notin {\rm dom}(\phi^2)$.

Comment: So the issue is really that your map need not even be composable with itself. It would be better to give these things names, because as soon as you write $\phi^2$, the assumption will be that $\phi$ *can* be composed with itself. Say, let $K_1=\mathrm{dom}(\phi)$, $K_2=K_1\cap\phi(K_1)$, $K_{n+1}=K_n\cap\phi(K_n)$...

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. I'll add an edit describing ${\rm dom}(\phi^n)$ in your notation.

Comment: This appears naturally in the contexts of commensuration of  the modular group and more general arithmetic groups. The intersection is typically trivial.

Comment: $K$ is nonempty (it contains $e$), but it need not be finite index or nontrivial. Defining a "left shift" defined only for tuples with trivial first entry in $\oplus_{i=1}^{\infty} C_2$ gives that the domain of the $n$th iterate is $\oplus_{i=1}^n\{1\}\oplus(\oplus_{i=n+1}^{\infty}C_2$, and their intersection is trivial.

Comment: @4plus4man does this 50 page book help?   https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81988923.pdf

Comment: @MathCrackExchange I suppose it is a reference that discusses "iterated homomorphisms", so thank you for pointing it out to me. It's a little impenetrable though. After a quick skim I'm unclear if it discusses anything directly applicable to my question. Was there something in it that you thought would be particularly useful?

Comment: @4plus4man Well, seems to be about algorithms looking very close to Collatz.  I ran into your same question studying Collatz, because the standard accelerated Collatz function is a semigroup homomorphism:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4740325/26327

I am also pausing on this; yes, all research papers are impenetrable to me too except a rare few.