# Shortcut Collatz function satisfies a particular functional equation. Has this approach been studied yet, and if so where are the reference articles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, functional-equations, semigroups, collatz-conjecture

Let $X = 2\Bbb{Z} + 1$ or $2 \Bbb{N} + 1$ where $0 \in \Bbb{N}$, this approach will probably play well with both forms.  See [Extending the Collatz function to larger domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Extensions_to_larger_domains).

Define the **shortcut Collatz function** to be:

$$
f : X \to X \\
f(x) = \dfrac{3x + 1}{2^{\nu_2(3x + 1)}}
$$

where $\nu_2(z)$ is the common notation meaning the maximum exponent $e$ of $2$ such that $2^e \mid z$.

Clearly then, the Collatz conjecture is equivalent to this function always taking its input (either in $\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{N}$) to one of the well-known finite loops.  For the $X = 2\Bbb{N} + 1$ form, this is the original Collatz conjecture.

But $f$ satisfies this equation:

$$
f(3xy + x +y) = f(x)f(y)
$$

*Proof.*  Simply multiply the RHS out and notice that $2^{\nu_2(3x + 1)} 2^{\nu_2(3y+1)} = 2^{\nu_2((3x + 1)(3y+1))}$.  So the numerator is $(3x + 1)(3y+1) = 9xy + 3x + 3y + 1 = 3(3xy + x + y) + 1$, and we're done, but the reader should write this out fully on paper. QED

So for instance $3(1)(1) + 1 + 1 = 5$ so that we know without a doubt that $f(5) = f(1)f(1) = 1$.

So if no reference exists that starts out with this simple observation, my question is this; in either form ($2\Bbb{N} + 1$ or $2\Bbb{Z} + 1 = X$), does the set:

$$
\{3xy + x + y: x,y \in X\}
$$

cover almost all of $X$?  By that I mean all but a finite number of values in $X$ are taken on by values of that polynomial expression where inputs are all pairs $(x,y) \in X^2$.

No idea how to solve this!

---

Notice that the law $x\star y := 3xy + x + y$ is a semigroup law on the set $X$.  I didn't prove this recently, but I recall that this is true from other posts I've made in the past.  You can prove it directly.  I don't know if this matters to Collatz, but it's just a note.  This implies that $f(x\star y) = f(x)f(y)$ or that the standard shortcut Collatz function, is also a semigroup homomorphism, although the $\star$ law is less natural to comprehend than the usual $\cdot$ on the RHS.

---

I want to say this kind of seems related to [Erdős covering systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system), since:

$$
\vdots \\
3(-3)x - 1 + x = -8x - 1 \\
3(-1)x - 1 + x = -2x - 1 \\
3(1)x + 1 + x = 4x + 1 \\
3(3)x + 3 + x = 10x + 3 \\
3(5)x + 5 + x = 16 x + 5 \\
\vdots
$$

But we merely want to cover odd numbers.  So to align this with the usual Erdos covers, we would take each residue class $a\Bbb{Z} + b$ and do: $\frac{a \Bbb{Z} + b - 1}{2}$, which will work because each modulus is even and each residue representative is odd.  We also must only pass in an odd number for $x$, so that would change the above list of residue classes completely.  It's doable though!

Comment: Your numbers are all $1\pmod 4$  Indeed, writing $x=2n+1, y=2m+1$ tells us that $3xy+x+y=3(2n+1)(2m+1)+2n+1+2m+1\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Comment: Oh, but not all numbers of the form $4n+1$ can be obtained by your method.  Barring computational error, I get the list of your numbers to be $\{5,13,21,29,33,37,45,53,\cdots\}$ so you are missing quite a few (I am taking $X$ to be the odd natural numbers here).

Comment: In any case, I do not see how this helps with Collatz.  It's not much of an observation to note that we can take out all the factors of $2$ in one step.

Comment: Of course one can do that, there is no problem doing that.  If $k$ is even, then $2^k\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ so we can solve $3n+1=2^k$, and Collatz is trivial for all such $n$.  And so on.

Comment: No offense intended.  I just don't see the idea.  Good luck, I will not comment further on this.

Comment: @lulu I apologize for being argumentative / taking offense.  I am currently in your boat now, I see no way to use this semigroup approach, so have to leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
from sympy import *

N = 50

def v2(n: int) -> int:
   k = 1
   while n % (2 ** k) == 0:
      k += 1
   k -= 1
   return k

def f(x: int) -> int:
   """Shortcut Collatz function"""
   assert x % 2 == 1
   return (3 * x + 1) // v2(3*x +1)

def semigroup_law(x:int, y:int):
   assert x % 2 == 1 and y % 2 == 1
   return 3 * x * y + x + y

values = set()

for m in range(-N, N):
   m = 2 * m + 1
   for n in range(-N, N):
      n = 2 * n + 1
      s = semigroup_law(m, n)
      values.add(s)
      
values = list(values)
values.sort(key=lambda v: abs(v))

print(values)
```

#### Prints:

```
 [1, -3, 5, -7, 9, -11, 13, -15, 17, -19, 21, -23, 25, -27, 29, -31, 33, -35, 37, -39, 41, -43, 45, -47, 49, -51, 53, -55, 57, -59, 61, ...]
```

#### Result

Probably easy to prove, is that while $3xy + x + y$ doesn't cover all $(4\Bbb{Z} + 1) \cup (4\Bbb{Z} + 3)$ for $x, y \in\Bbb{Z}$, we have that the absolute value $|3xy + x + y|$ covers all $2\Bbb{N} + 1, (0 \in \Bbb{N})$.  And so if we consider all the $X = 2\Bbb{Z} + 1$ form of Collatz, then $4\Bbb{N} + 1$ gets covered and so does $-(4\Bbb{N} + 3)$.

Comment: Donnely : I heard that collatz is equivalent to proving collatz for imputs 3n.